# NSLocalNotification badgecount issues

Tags: ios

I have a quick question that I'm hoping someone can help with.

I'm writing an app that sends a series of local notifications to remind a user about something several times a day. The problem i'm having is with the badge count. I schedule several reminders at one time (6/day) and currently the badge count goes up when the notification is scheduled, not when it is received. I can get it to count down when the user opens the app and performs the necessary tasks, but I don't want all 6 to show up when the app first schedules them. Any ideas?

This is how I have been adding up the badge count.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;
```

}